# Angular dependent select boxes doesn't work

Tags: json, angular, nested, rxjs, angular-ngmodel

The first box works well. But the second one doesn't work. They depend on each other. And the error does not appear.

I can't try anything else because it doesn't any errors.

city.service.ts

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class CityService {

  constructor(private http:Http) { }
      getCitys(){
    return this.http.get("http://localhost:3003/api")
      .map(response => response.json());
  }
}
```

city.ts

```
export interface City 
  { 
   name: string,
   value:number,
   down: Down[]
  }
export interface Down
         {
   name: string,
   value:number,
   places: Places[]
}

  export interface Places    
          {
   name: string;
   pname:string;
   unvan: string
  }
```

city.component.ts

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-city',
  templateUrl: './city.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./city.component.css']
})
export class CityComponent implements OnInit {
  cityDatas: [];
downDatas: [];
placesDatas: [];

  constructor(private cityService: CityService) { }

  ngOnInit() {
           this.cityService.getCitys().subscribe(d => { 
        this.cityDatas = d;
        this.downDatas = d.down;
        this.placesDatas = d.places });

  }


}
```

city.component.html

```
  <select [(ngModel)]="selectedData">
    <option [ngValue]="null" selected disabled>First</option>
      <option *ngFor="let data of cityDatas" [value]="data">
        {{ data.name }}
      </option>
    </select>

            <select [(ngModel)]="selectedDw" >
      <option [ngValue]="null"  selected disabled>Second</option>
        <option *ngFor="let dw of downDatas" [value]="dw">
          {{dw.name}}
        </option>
    </select>
```

And api json

```
[
      {"name":"City1",
      "value":1,
      "down":
        [{"name":"Down11",
        "value":101,
        "places":
          [{"name":"Place111",
            "pname":"JustPlace",
            "unvan":"center"
          },
        {"name":"Place112",
            "pname":"Jp",
            "unvan":"center"
          }]
        },
{"name":"Down12",
        "value":102,
        "places":
          [{"name":"Place121",
            "pname":"Jp",
            "unvan":"side"
          },
        {"name":"Place122",
            "pname":"Jp",
            "unvan":"side"
          }]
        }
      ]
      },
            {"name":"City2",
      "value":2,
      "down":
        [{"name":"Down21",
        "value":103,
        "places":
          [{"name":"Place211",
            "pname":"Jp",
            "unvan":"center"
          },
        {"name":"Place212",
            "pname":"Jp",
            "unvan":"center"
          }]
        },
{"name":"Down22",
        "value":104,
        "places":
          [{"name":"Place221",
            "pname":"JustPlace",
            "unvan":"side"
          },
        {"name":"Place222",
            "pname":"Jp",
            "unvan":"side"
          }]
        }
      ]
      }
     ]
```

When I choose the first one, I want the second to work. And I want the results displayed. But I couldn't run the second select box and the console didn't give any errors.
Why does not work? And how will it work?

Comment: d s an array so s.down is null

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`downDatas` is `undefined`, because `d` in the subscription is an `array`, not an `object`. Try to implement it in this way (after selecting `selectedData` in the first select, this data will be available in the second):

```
<select [(ngModel)]="selectedData">
  <option selected disabled>First</option>
  <option *ngFor="let data of cityDatas; index as i;" [value]="i">
    {{ data.name }}
  </option>
</select>

<select [(ngModel)]="selectedDw" >
  <option [ngValue]="null"  selected disabled>Second</option>
  <option *ngFor="let dw of cityDatas[selectedData]?.down" [value]="dw">
    {{ dw.name }}
  </option>
</select>
```

[stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-dependent-select-boxes-doesnt-work)

Comment: I'm using the rxjs observable. Does it also work in them?

Comment: It didn't work. "ERROR TypeError: "_co.selectedData is undefined""

Comment: @ucnumara initialize `cityData` as an empty array here: `export class CityComponent implements OnInit { cityDatas = [];`. I've edited `stackblitz`, added timeout to make it close to async actions. Also, pay attention to this part `cityDatas[selectedData]?`...here sign `?` check for `undefiend`.

Comment: @ucnumara  `http://myjson.com/19dle4`  for getting `json` is not right. Check [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-dependent2-nyssch?file=src%2Fapp%2Fcity%2Fcity.component.ts). I've change path for `json` and just paste code from my answer to `city.component.html`.

Answer (score 0):

You need implement `change` event of city select tag and update `datasource` for downDatas

```
onChange($event, cityid) {
   let selectedcity = this.cityDatas.filter(c=>c.value == cityid)[0];
   console.log(JSON.stringify(selectedcity))
   this.downDatas = selectedcity.down;
  }
```

HTML

```
<select [(ngModel)]="selectedData" #city (change)="onChange($event, city.value)">
```

Demo https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-city-down?file=src/app/app.component.ts

Comment: It didn't work. 
error TS2339: Property 'value' does not exist on type 'never'.
error TS2339: Property 'down' does not exist on type 'never'.

Comment: Did you set (change)="onChange($event, city.value)" on HTML?

Comment: Yes, I added it.

Comment: Did you try my demo?